# How to load a large csv file into Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to load a large csv file (*1458644 row*) into neo4j, but i'm still getting this error :

```
Neo.TransientError.General.OutOfMemoryError: There is not enough memory to perform the current task. Please try increasing 'dbms.memory.heap.max_size' in the neo4j configuration (normally in 'conf/neo4j.conf' or, if you you are using Neo4j Desktop, found through the user interface) or if you are running an embedded installation increase the heap by using '-Xmx' command line flag, and then restart the database.
```

even if i change  `dbms.memory.heap.max_size=1024m`   with m=megbite , the same error occurs again !

*Note :* the size of the csv is **195.888 KB**

this is my code :

```
load csv with headers from "file:///train.csv" as line
create(pl:pickup_location{latitude:toFloat(line.pickup_latitude),longitude:toFloat(line.pickup_longitude)}),(pt:pickup_time{pickup:line.pickup_datetime}),(dl:dropoff_location{latitude:toFloat(line.dropoff_latitude),longitude:toFloat(line.dropoff_longitude)}),(dt:dropoff_time{dropoff:line.dropoff_datetime})
create (pl)-[:TLR]->(pt),(dl)-[:TLR]->(dt),(pl)-[:Trip]->(dl);
```

what should i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved the problem by copying the solution for limited row [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45809240/load-only-few-samples-from-large-csv-file-in-neo4j)

so this is my solution:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
load csv with headers from "file:///train.csv" as line
with line LIMIT 1458644
create   (pl:pickup_location{latitude:toFloat(line.pickup_latitude),longitude:toFloat(line.pickup_longitude)}),(pt:pickup_time{pickup:line.pickup_datetime}),(dl:dropoff_location{latitude:toFloat(line.dropoff_latitude),longitude:toFloat(line.dropoff_longitude)}),(dt:dropoff_time{dropoff:line.dropoff_datetime})
create (pl)-[:TLR]->(pt),(dl)-[:TLR]->(dt),(pl)-[:Trip]->(dl);
```

the downside of this solution is that you need to know the number of rows of your big csv file (*excel* can't open large csv files).

Comment: Hmm. This is essentially the same as my answer, except that you added a totally unnecessary `with line LIMIT 1458644` clause.

Comment: sorry, before you answer ,the script(*my answer*) was  running for 30 min.
i didn't tried your answer yet, i will try it and if it work i will mark it as the answer for the question

Answer (score 1):

You should use [periodic commits](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/clauses/load-csv/#load-csv-importing-large-amounts-of-data) to process the CSV data in batches. For example, this will process 10,000 lines at a time (the default batch size is 1000):

```
USING PERIOD COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///train.csv" as line
CREATE (pl:pickup_location{latitude:toFloat(line.pickup_latitude),longitude:toFloat(line.pickup_longitude)}),(pt:pickup_time{pickup:line.pickup_datetime}),(dl:dropoff_location{latitude:toFloat(line.dropoff_latitude),longitude:toFloat(line.dropoff_longitude)}),(dt:dropoff_time{dropoff:line.dropoff_datetime})
CREATE (pl)-[:TLR]->(pt),(dl)-[:TLR]->(dt),(pl)-[:Trip]->(dl);
```