# Out of memory in neo4j using periodic commits

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to load a pretty large (~200 million rows) file in neo4j using `LOAD CSV` like this

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///home/manu/citation.csv.gz' AS line
MATCH (origin:`publication` {`id`: line.`cite_from`})
MATCH (destination:`publication` {`id`: line.`cite_to`})
MERGE (origin )-[rel:CITES ]->(destination );
```

but I keep seeing memory errors such as

```
raise CypherError.hydrate(**metadata)
neo4j.exceptions.TransientError: There is not enough memory to perform 
the current task. Please try increasing 'dbms.memory.heap.max_size' in 
the neo4j configuration (normally in 'conf/neo4j.conf' or, if you you 
are using Neo4j Desktop, found through the user interface) or if you 
are running an embedded installation increase the heap by using '-Xmx' 
command line flag, and then restart the database.
```

when running the code, and in the server

```
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "neo4j.StorageMaintenance-14"
2018-12-05 15:44:32.967+0000 WARN   Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2018-12-05 15:44:32.968+0000 WARN  Unexpected thread death: org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2@b6328a3 in QueuedThreadPool[qtp483052300]@1ccacb0c{STARTED,8<=8<=14,i=1,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@f5cbd17{s=0/1,p=0}]
Exception in thread "neo4j.ServerTransactionTimeout-6" Exception in thread "neo4j.TransactionTimeoutMonitor-11" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space                                              
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap
```

Of course I tried setting this `dbms.memory.heap.max_size` thing (up to 24 GB...above that, my 32-GB machine will not even be able to start neo4j), but am still getting those. The thing I don't quite get is: what's the purpose of the `USING PERIODIC COMMIT` part if (it seems) neo4j tries to load everything at once? When looking at the [manual](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/query-tuning/using/#query-using-periodic-commit-hint) or, e.g., [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50975631/how-to-load-a-large-csv-file-into-neo4j) you would think `USING PERIODIC COMMIT` is a fix for exactly the problem I'm having.

Any clue? The only workaround that comes to mind is splitting the file in several pieces, but that doesn't look like an elegant solution (also, if that works...couldn't neo4j do that for me transparently?)

EDIT: the query plan using `EXPLAIN`

[image]

Cheers.

Comment: The query itself looks good, I don't see anything there that would disable periodic commits. Can you run an EXPLAIN of the query, expand all elements of the plan, and attach the query plan image to your description?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply!! I just uploaded the working plan (by the way early `id` is now `scopus_id` (not that it matters...probably)

Comment: The plan looks good too. Can you confirm if `id` is supposed to uniquely identify a publication, or can that result in multiple matched nodes per id? You may also want to see if explicitly [using a lower value for periodic commit](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/load-csv/#load-csv-setting-the-rate-of-periodic-commits) might help

Comment: yes, `id` is unique, also I had tried before `USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000` and after a long time *neo4j browser* became unresponsive and most of my system's memory was taken up by java...so I ctrl-c'ed it. Anyway, I found a "solution": creating a UNIQUE constraint on the `id` property does the trick :D Thanks for the input!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably more a workaround than a "solution" but putting a UNIQUE constraint on the property that is extensively checked for that *cypher* query did the trick for me:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (p:publication) ASSERT p.id IS UNIQUE
```